# Will os.system("color") in a script cause trouble if the program runs in Mac OS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, ansi-colors

I have a set of text-analysis programs in Python. I want the menu and selected Terminal output to be in various colors. I have it working as desired by including `os.system("color")` at the beginning and using ANSI codes (shown in the code snippet). My understanding is that these codes are native to other OS's, but if I include `os.system("color")`, will the program crash on a Mac? If so, is there an error-trapping routine I can use to prevent it?

```
CLR = {
"M": "\033[95m",
"B": "\033[94m",
"G": "\033[92m",
"R": "\033[91m",
"Y": "\033[93m",
"C": "\033[96m",
"NO": "\033[0m",}

print(CLR["M"], "Testing Magenta!!", CLR["NO"])
print(CLR["B"], "Testing Blue!!", CLR["NO"])
print(CLR["G"], "Testing Green!!", CLR["NO"])
print(CLR["R"], "Testing Red!!", CLR["NO"])
print(CLR["Y"], "Testing Yellow!!", CLR["NO"])
print(CLR["C"], "Testing Cyan!!", CLR["NO"])
```

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(['color'], shell=False)` will actually throw an exception if the command you're running doesn't exist -- at least, on UNIX-y platforms; you'd need to test on Windows.

Comment: Consider using a curses library to get the right color codes for the currently active terminal -- you don't want to assume that the terminal the user is currently using is their operating system's default (even if there is such a thing; on Linux-y systems, for example, different distros will use different desktop environments with different terminal emulators, and a system with a GUI running will have a different TERM value than one without).

Answer (score 1):

Normally one might catch exceptions/errors with a `try/catch` block, however `os.system` never throw an exception so long as you provide it with a string, even if the string does not contain a valid command.

Instead of trying if `os.system('color')` works and catching the error later you could check what OS the user is running before calling anything. This can be done with `sys.platform`:

```py
import os, sys 
if sys.platform == "win32":
    os.system('color')
elif sys.platform == "linux" or sys.platform == "linux2":
    # Linux specific stuff
elif sys.platform == "darwin":
    # MacOS specific stuff
```